# Radius of convergence of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, solution-verification

> Find the radius of convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{in}n!z^{n^2}$$ and determine whether the sum converges on its circle of convergence.

My solution: let $R$ denote the radius of convergence. Then $R=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mid\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}\mid$. This gives the following:

$$R=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mid\frac{e^{i(n+1)}(n+1)!z^{(n+1)^2}}{e^{in}n!z^{n^2}}\mid=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mid(n+1)e^iz^{2n+1}\mid=\infty$$ since $n+1\rightarrow\infty$. Thus the radius of convergence is $0$. As to whether the sum converges on its circle of convergence; its circle of convergence is simply a point, that is $z=0$. Then the sum *should* converge I would have thought, making this rigorous is not so easy.

Answer (score 1):

A few mistakes in your question, but instead of focusing on that, I'll just write down a solution:

$\left|\dfrac{e^{i(n+1)}(n+1)!z^{(n+1)^2}}{e^{in}n!z^{n^2}}\right|=|(n+1)e^iz^{2n+1}|$

which tends to $0$ if $|z|<1$, but which tends to $\infty$ if $|z|\geq1$.

By the ratio test for convergent series, the series converges precisely when $|z|<1$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm slightly confused though, why must it converge if $|z|<1$? I cam see how this would be the case if there wasn't an $n+1$ term in front of it...

Comment: @turtle111 for example, how does $(n+1)\times(0.5)^n=\dfrac{n+1}{2^n}$ behave?

Comment: I can see why this converges - in general how can we tell though? Like if we got $f(n)=n^nz$, we could say if $|z|<1$ we get convergence? I'm confused

Comment: @turtle111 first task prove that if $|z|<1$ then $f(n)=|(n+1)e^iz^{2n+1}|$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity. Hint: what is $\dfrac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}$?

Comment: Second task: Using the ratio test for convergent series, prove that if $|z|<1$, then $
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{in}n!z^{n^2}$ converges. Link to ratio test https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test